# How to upload Image using retrofit2 multipart?

Tags: android, image, retrofit2, multipart

I totally got struct in uploading an image on server. I'm getting response from server successfully but image is not getting upload on server. Always asking for "Insert Your Image".

**here is my code** please check this, where i'm making mistake

```
private void uploadFile(Uri fileUri) {
    File file = new File(fileUri.getPath());
    if (file.exists()) {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        Log.e(TAG, "uploadFile:File "+file );
        MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_PNG = MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data");

        APIInterface service = retrofit.create(APIInterface.class);

        RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, file);
        Log.e(TAG, "uploadUri: " + strEmpsno + " " + strStoreSno + "  " + strLrno + "  " + strRecqty + "  " + strDeliverydate + " " + strDeliverytime);
        Call<PODResponse> call = service.postFile(strEmpsno, strStoreSno, strLrno, strRecqty, strRecvol,
                strRecwgt, strDamageqty, strLooseqty, strDeliverydate
                , strDeliverytime, requestFile, strRemarks, strReceivedby,
                strIpaddress);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<PODResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<PODResponse> response) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onResponse:uploadUri " + response.isSuccess());
                if (response.isSuccess()) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "uploadUri: " + response.body().getResult());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onFailure:uploadUri " + t.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        });
    }
  }
```

In log of `Log.e(TAG, "uploadFile:File "+file );` i'm getting

> /storage/emulated/0/Audex/saved_images/logo.jpg

This is my `Image name with path`. From `Rest(chrome extension)` image is successfully getting stored on server but not by using this code. Please help me.

**My Interface is like**

```
  @Multipart
@POST("/savePic")
Call<PODResponse> postFile(
        @Part("empsno") String empsno,
        @Part("storesno") String storesno,
        @Part("lrSno") String lrSno,
        @Part("recQty") String recQty,
        @Part("recVol") String recVol,
        @Part("recWgt") String recWgt,
        @Part("damageQty") String damageQty,
        @Part("looseQty") String looseQty,
        @Part("deliveryDate") String deliveryDate,
        @Part("deliveryTime") String deliveryTime,
        @Part("uploadFile\"; filename=\"audex.jpg\" ") RequestBody part,
        @Part("remarks") String remarks,
        @Part("receivedBy") String receivedBy,
        @Part("ipAddress") String ipAddress
);
```

**Thank you All in advance**

Comment: `I'm getting response from server successfully `. Where and how do you get such a response?

Comment: `response.body().getResult())`. Lease tell what you get there.

Comment: `response.body().getResult())` here i'm getting response from server

Comment: actually i'm getting `response.isSuccess() = true` i'm getting

Comment: `here i'm getting response from server –`. Yes of course. Do you think we dont know that? But what is the response? Tell us! I asked you.

Comment: you have to use `RequestBody token = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "Token");` every string value ..... change value after read my answer

Comment: thats what i told you **Insert your Image** this is the response from server

Comment: @sushildlh you want me to change string to RequestBody in all

Comment: yes try ...............

Comment: i tried in that way also but not successfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long long time i got my answer. Thanks all who tried for me. Only error was i was putting RequestBody instead of String.

```
  @Multipart
  @POST("/savePic")
  Call<PODResponse> postFile(
    @Part("empsno") String empsno,
    @Part("storesno") String storesno,
    @Part("lrSno") String lrSno,
    @Part("recQty") String recQty,
    @Part("recVol") String recVol,
    @Part("recWgt") String recWgt,
    @Part("damageQty") String damageQty,
    @Part("looseQty") String looseQty,
    @Part("deliveryDate") String deliveryDate,
    @Part("deliveryTime") String deliveryTime,
    @Part("uploadFile\"; filename=\"audex.jpg\" ") String part, // Change here
    @Part("remarks") String remarks,
    @Part("receivedBy") String receivedBy,
    @Part("ipAddress") String ipAddress
    @Part MultipartBody.Part images
);
```

`@Part("uploadFile\"; filename=\"audex.jpg\" ") String part` simply i made changes from RequestBody to string and in last add `@Part MultipartBody.Part images` that's it.

**Dependency I used is

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit-converters:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.0.2'
```